# Procedure Failed to create compilation error

Tags: oracle, procedure

```
create or replace procedure testpga( psize number ) as
begin
declare
TYPE nAllotment_tabtyp IS TABLE OF char(2048) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
myarray nAllotmen_tabtyp;
begin
for i in 1.. psize_loop

myarray(i) := to_char(i);`bold`
end loop;
end;
```

enter code here

end;`enter code here`
/

LINE/COL ERROR

---

8/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "MYARRAY" when expecting one
of the following:
. ( * @ % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem
<an exponent (**)> || multiset
The symbol "." was substituted for "MYARRAY" to continue.

8/12     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
following:
. ( * % & - + / at loop mod remainder rem <an exponent (**)>
|| multiset

LINE/COL ERROR

---

9/1  PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of
the following:
begin function pragma procedure subtype type 
 current cursor delete
exists prior

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace procedure testpga( psize number )
as
  TYPE nAllotment_tabtyp IS TABLE OF char(2048) INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  myarray nAllotment_tabtyp;
begin
  for i in 1.. psize
  loop
    myarray(i) := to_char(i); --'bold'
  end loop;
end;
```

I suggest reading the *PL/SQL Language Reference* which is part of the Oracle database documentation and available online.